# angular two way binding with JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Actually i have one JSON in scope. I need to change that JSON values whenever the ng-model will get change. In the below example JSON having rowset with attributes (CuId,Name,Quantity,Rate,Amount). These attribute names i have to bind the with control(textbox) like ng-model=CuId. So whenever the corresponding attributes value will get change the JSON need to be update.

Please provide any example related to this or suggest me how to achieve this.

JSON:

```
 $scope.postJSON =   {
      "entityInfo": {
        "entity": "",
        "tenantId": "",
        "timeStamp": "2016-04-07T09:37:16.187Z"
      },
      "collections": {
        "Customer29Jan16": {
          "meta": {
            "parentreference": "***",
            "pkname": "***",
            "fkname": "***"
          },
          "rowset": [
            {
              "CuId": "test",
              "Name": "test",
              "Quantity": "test",
              "Rate": "test",
              "Amount": "test"
            }
          ],
          "rowfilter": []
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did u check. Since angular has two way data binding, any change you make to the model will reflect in the json. You just have to access the element properly and add it as an ng-model in your html.

Comment: Use something like `ng-model="postJSON.collections.rowset[0].CuId"`.

Comment: @ViChU Yes I checked and I did small example using two way binding but i need one complex example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answers have mentioned, you need to use the entire tree down to the property you want to change. However, they didn't mention that since `rowset` is an array, you also have to specify which element of `rowset` you want to access.  Use something like `ng-model="postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset[0].CuId"`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the whole tree in the ng-model. Like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset.CuId" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input ng-model="postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset[0].CuId" />
```

or, to make things more compact, put the rowset on the scope:

```
$scope.rowset = $scope.postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset[0];
```

then use:

```
<input ng-model="rowset.CuId" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You've added `postData` to the scope so you can bind onto individual attributes like so.

```
<input ng-model="postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset[0].CuId" />
<input ng-model="postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset[0].Name" />
<input ng-model="postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset[0].Quantity" />
<input ng-model="postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset[0].Rate" />
<input ng-model="postJSON.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset[0].Amount" />
```